# undefined method `namespace' for #<Jquery::Rails::Engine:0x102530798> in rake db:create:ll

Tags: ruby, rake

When running `rake db:create:all` I get an the following error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `namespace' for #<Jquery::Rails::Engine:0x102530798>
```

The rakefile looks as follows:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

module ::TestProject
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end

TestProject::Application.load_tasks
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that have solved your problems by clicking on the green tick next to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I add `Rake::DSL` before `TestProject::Application.load_tasks` to make it works. I don't know if it's good, but it works for me ! (Sorry if I made mistakes, I speak French.)

Comment: @Martin: Then click on the tick next to this answer!

Comment: took me more than 5 minutes to find the tick - but finally i did it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed adding:

`include Rake::DSL`

just before load_tasks helped fixing the same issue for me.